# Dynamic binding of services in Thrift or gRPC / passing service as argument

Tags: callback, grpc, thrift

I work with existing system that uses a lot of dynamic service registrations, using Andorid HIDL/AIDL, for example:

Multiple objects implement:

```
IHandler { Response handleRequet(Id subset, Request r)}
```

One object implements:

```
class IHandlerCoordinator {
   Response handleRequet(Id subset, Request r);
   void RegisterHandler(std::vector<Id> subsets, IHandler handler_for_subset_ids);
}
```

Multiple object on startup/dynamicaly register into IHandlerCoordinator (passing expected subset of what they can handle), and then IHandlerCoordinator dispatches incoming requests to clients.

In xIDL it requires passing services as arguments, how it can be emulated in Thrift / gRPC?

Answer (score 1):

W/regard to Thrift: There is no such thing as callbacks yet. There have been some dicussions around that topic (see mailing list archives and/or JIRA) but there's no implementation. Biggest challenge is to do it in an transport-agnositic way, so the current consensus is that you have to implement it manually if you need it.

Technically, there's two general ways to do it:

- implement a server instance also on the client side which receives the callbacks
- integrate long running calls or a polling mechanism to actively retrieve "callback" data from the server by means of client calls

With gRPC it's easier, because gRPC focuses on HTTP. Thrift has been open from the beginning for [any kind of transport you can imagine](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2549).

Comment: With implementing the server on the client side as well - that sounds OK, is the practice then that in "register call" you pass unix path or URL instead of handle?

Comment: Whatever you need :-) URL, Pipe Handle, Socket port ... you name it.